# 3-D view of .ovr bathymetry raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, 3d, bathymetry

I am working with .ovr format a bathymetry data in ArcGIS Pro. The dataset has the following 4 files (name.asc, name.asc.aux.xml, name.asc.ovr, and name.prj) When I add click "add data" to map and choose "rasters(all local types)" only the name.asc file is shown. I added the .asc file to my map. In the contents pane the layer shows the bathymetry elevation ranges from -11 to -1,200. I then created a local scene. However, in the 3-D local scene the layer appears to be above sea level. How can I generate a scene that appears below sea level?

Comment: The .ovr file contains the reduced resolution versions of the main file (.asc). The name .ovr stands for "overviews", sometimes called as pyramid layers. So seeing just .asc is normal. Unfortunately I can't answer on how to make the 3-D scene behave correctly.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is, perhaps a picture would help. You may need to mask (clip) out your local scene where the bathymetry is present.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the local scene for the bathymetry is flat. The depths range from -11 feet to -1,200 feet below sea level, but the local scene shows a flat surface above sea level. My specific question is what should I do to make it show at the correct depths.